# C++: copying bmp using loop of fread and fwrite, casues output bmp is filled with color of the fisrt one in input bmp

Tags: fread, bmp, fwrite

I dunno why, but first pixel (left bottom) is loaded correctly, but the others won't load and the first color is used for whole picture...

I have this in cycle

```
fread(&pix,sizeof(pix),1,pictureIn);
fwrite(&pix,sizeof(pix),1,pictureOut);
```

edit:

pix is struct of three unsigned chars (rgb), loading file and info header seems to be ok

Comment: You haven't given enough information.  What is pix?  How do you know the size?

Comment: Do you actually check the return values so you can tell if something went wrong?

Comment: And presumably you opened a file? How did you do it? Did you, for example, open it in binary mode? And is this in a loop? You get the idea - we are not mind readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you using? I recently had problem with reading binary files under Win32. It turned out that I forgot to pass "b" flag to fopen:

```
pictureIn = fopen ("in.bmp", "rb");
pictureOut = fopen ("out.bmp", "wb");
```